# How to show date from MonthCalendar to TextBox C#

Tags: c#, textbox, monthcalendar

I have two forms, on one is month, on another is TextBox.
Problem is that I don't get displayed date on the TextBox after selecting it.
To be certain that I wrote working code, I did same thing just on one form, and it works fine.
Set MonthCalendar to public and same with the TextBox where date needs to be displayed.
[image]

Here is the code for Button and for the monthcalendar:

```
public void mcKalendar_DateChanged()
{
    frmNovoVozilo fNv = new frmNovoVozilo();
    fNv.txtDatKupovine.Text =
          mcKalendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
}

private void btnDatum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmKalendar fKalen = new frmKalendar();
    fKalen.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    fKalen.Show();
}
```

Did try also DateSelected and it's giving me the same result, nothing.
Thanks upfornt.

Comment: The problem you are having is that you are trying to reference a form outside the scope of the second form. Unless you reference the original form in the creation of your second, you cant affect changes. See my answer for 2 methods you can achieve your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to transfer the value to the previous form, is to use form closing event handlers and get/set methods to extract the value. For example:

```
form1 = new Form1();
form1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(GetDateFromForm);

private void GetDateFromForm(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = from1.GetDate;
}
```

then in your month calendar form, use

```
string date;

public string GetDate {get {return date;} set {date = value;}}

Public Form2()
{
    date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
}
```

once you close the calendar, the selected value will be transfered.

Another method is to send a reference to the form you want to apply the changes to in the constructor of the second form.

in your primary form (the one with the button) when you create the popup form, use the syntax `Form2 calendarform = new Form2(this)` and write a public method that does what you need to

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    textbox.Text = text;
}
```

In your second form (the one with the month calendar) you will be able to refer to the previous method. For example:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 _owner;

    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _owner = form;
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _owner.SetText(monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString());
    }
```

Because we are referencing the previous form in the second form, you are able to call all the public methods that will run on form1. So in this case you can call the `SetText()` method from form2, which will change the textbox to whatever we want - in your case the selected value of the monthcalendar.

Using the `DateChanged` method means that it will call said method in real time as you change the date.

Comment: Since I'm new to the C# I do need help with syntax on some lines. In the second method where does "Form2 calendarform = new Form2(this)" go?
I get: "this" keyword is not available in the context.

Comment: the `this` part basically means "this object". so in this case, `this` means send form1 to the second form. The constructor for the second form needs to take Form1 as a value. ie `Form2(Form1 originalform)`

Comment: You need to put the `Form2 calendarform = new Form2(this)` part in your button that calls your monthcalander form